# MS ACCESS: Force showing only X field in combobox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

So far, all I have found are answers that suggest I show all fields up until the the field I want and hiding the other fields by reducing their size to 0, but is there any way to force the combobox to only show the field I want without requiring I adjust column sizes?

**CLARIFICATION:**

1. When I set BoundColumn = 2, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQClu.png) result.
2. So far, I have only been able to find solutions that require I set ColumnCount = 2 and set the ColumnWidths = 0";x" to hide the 1st column as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDuQG.png).

Q: Is there no way that I can simply pick [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3QEH.png) column to be the source for the combobox without doing as was described in sentence 2?

I hope that sufficiently clarifies my question.

It seems like this should be an obvious feature and I don't understand why it's not.

If a solution does exist that I haven't found yet, then kindly direct me to it.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not clear what you're asking, can you please include an explanation of how you came across the problem, and what you have tried to do to fix it? Screenshots might help in this case. See [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the data/row source of the combobox can bet set as

```
 SELECT yourColumn FROM tbl;
```

[image]

Then you dont have to bother with setting bound column or anything else.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm trying to limit the number of single-use queries and I was pulling my hair out.